# SendGrid Single Sender Verification works with messages@domain.com email but not with messages+xxxxxxx@domain.com email

Tags: sendgrid-api-v3

From May 1st of this year, SendGrid has made it mandatory to perform Sender Verification. We can perform sender verification by either verifying a domain or a specific email address. In my case, I have verified a specific email - messages@domain.com. Now I am sending emails using SendGrid API from my web application. I am setting the from value to messages+xxxxxxx@domain.com. But, SendGrid throws the following error:

`java.io.IOException: Request returned status Code 403Body:{"errors":[{"message":"The from address does not match a verified Sender Identity. Mail cannot be sent until this error is resolved. Visit https://sendgrid.com/docs/for-developers/sending-email/sender-identity/ to see the Sender Identity requirements","field":"from","help":null}]}`

SendGrid does not treat messages@domain.com and messages+xxxxxxx@domain.com as the same. For various reasons, I cannot verify the domain. Hence, how can I perform sender verification for the above use case?

Comment: Imo this is the right behavior as almost platforms would consider these to be different email addresses. Have you tried doing a second single sender verification for messages+xxxxxxx@domain.com?

Comment: I would not be able to verify messages+xxxxxxx@domain.com as the xxxxxxxx part of the email is dynamic. It would change for each email that is sent by the application.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid this is the correct behavior and there is not workaround besides verifying the domain or all individual senders that you want to use.